# Clearing cluster in infinispan lucene index

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search, clustered-index, infinispan

I have used Hibernate Search and have used Infinispan to store Lucene indexes.
The configurations are as follows:
in persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.search.[default|plindexes].directory_provider"                value="org.hibernate.search.infinispan.impl.InfinispanDirectoryProvider" />
```

and added dependency in pom.xml file as mentioned in 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#infinispan-directories

Everything works great.

Now, I want to clear the indexes created in cluster by infinispan.
How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically you could use the *FullTextSession.purge*  or *FullTextSession.purgeAll* methods.